# First slide in HTML Slider not displaying upon initial page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an HTML slider template that I followed from W3 Schools, I followed the template to put a slideshow on a Facebook page my company manages using raw HTML. My issue, is that when the page is first loaded, the first slide does not display at all. It is not until the user continues to the next slide that the image loads.
I have compared my code to the original, and there should be nothing wrong, as I literally just used the template and changed a few text/button colors.


Here is the template I followed: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp


Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Woobox Digital Deals Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

</script>

<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Heading Text */
#slideshow-heading {
    color: rgba(222,42,0,1.00); /*Primary site color goes here*/
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px
}

/*Comment styling*/ 
.text {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
</style>


<div>
    <p id="slideshow-heading">
        Click or Tap image to print
    </p>
</div>
 <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.shoppingindanville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Artboard-19.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="http://www.shoppingindanville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Artboard-18.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="http://www.shoppingindanville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Artboard-17.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to @Zerone for explaining to me why my code was not working. I did not realize that as the page was loaded, it executed the code is sequential order. This helps expand my understanding of how HTML behaves, thank you again Zerone!

Comment: Just put the script tag in the end of you html inside body,it will work fine :)
DEMO:http://jsbin.com/bobasebemi/2/edit?html,output

Comment: I'll be damned. Now I have a question in return, why does that work?

Comment: by putting  the script tag in the end  you ran your script after all elements are loaded(ie accessible by script).By putting your script above the first slide wasnt visible but on clicking nxt/back you call the function hence desired output(as function is called after elements are loaded)


footnote:read this article for better knowledge https://github.com/bendc/frontend-guidelines

Comment: Thank you so much @Zerone . Seriously appreciated. I am still relatively new to web programming, so any help and pointers are greatly appreciated, and it helps improve my knowledge of how web languages function and behave.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your script block down to the bottom of your html, after your last div and before the body tag like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Woobox Digital Deals Slider</title>
</head>

<body>



<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Heading Text */
#slideshow-heading {
    color: rgba(222,42,0,1.00); /*Primary site color goes here*/
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px
}

/*Comment styling*/ 
.text {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
</style>


<div>
    <p id="slideshow-heading">
        Click or Tap image to print
    </p>
</div>
 <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.shoppingindanville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Artboard-19.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="http://www.shoppingindanville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Artboard-18.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="http://www.shoppingindanville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Artboard-17.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

That stops the Java executing until the rest of the page content has loaded :)

Comment: Thank you! @Zerone posted the same thing and it solved my issue a couple days ago. But any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

When a browser sees the entire page you provided, it will go from top to bottom. This means that it sees the JavaScript first and will try to execute:

```
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

before your the elements with class name "MySlides" are generated, so it doesn't know what to do. The solution is what Zerone proposed